# What is proper Partition configs for Dagster job?

Tags: dagster

Currently, I am facing with `dagster.core.errors.PartitionExecutionError` but error logs from Dagster seem not obvious to me.

```
dagster.core.errors.PartitionExecutionError: Error occurred during the evaluation of the `run_config_for_partition` function for partition set download_firebase_data_local_partition_set 
  File "/Users/bryan/miniconda3/envs/dagster-injector/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/grpc/impl.py", line 292, in get_partition_config
    return ExternalPartitionConfigData(name=partition.name, run_config=run_config)
  File "/Users/bryan/miniconda3/envs/dagster-injector/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/Users/bryan/miniconda3/envs/dagster-injector/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/core/errors.py", line 192, in user_code_error_boundary
    raise error_cls(
The above exception was caused by the following exception:

TypeError: daily_download_config() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given 
  File "/Users/bryan/miniconda3/envs/dagster-injector/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/core/errors.py", line 185, in user_code_error_boundary
    yield
  File "/Users/bryan/miniconda3/envs/dagster-injector/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/grpc/impl.py", line 291, in get_partition_config
    run_config = partition_set_def.run_config_for_partition(partition)
  File "/Users/bryan/miniconda3/envs/dagster-injector/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/core/definitions/partition.py", line 441, in run_config_for_partition
    return copy.deepcopy(self._user_defined_run_config_fn_for_partition(partition))
  File "/Users/bryan/miniconda3/envs/dagster-injector/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/core/definitions/time_window_partitions.py", line 192, in <lambda>
    run_config_for_partition_fn=lambda partition: fn(
```

My current setup is

```
@graph
def download():
    """
    Download data from BigQuery then upload to S3
    """
    extract_data_in_date()


@daily_partitioned_config(start_date=datetime(2021, 12, 1))
def daily_download_config(date: datetime):
    return {
        "resources": {
            "date": date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        }
    }

download_local_job = download.to_job(
    name=f'{NAME}_local',
    resource_defs={
        **{
            "date": make_values_resource(date=str),
            "project_name": ResourceDefinition.hardcoded_resource("test-123")
        },
        **RESOURCES_LOCAL,
    },
    config=daily_download_config,
    executor_def=in_process_executor
)
```

I am not sure where I am wrong, can you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@daily_paritioned_config` needs to be able to accept two arguments, one for the start of the time window and one for the end. `daily_download_config` doesn't actually make use of this end date value, but it still needs to show up in the signature because Dagster will try to pass two arguments to this function regardless